# Execute Shell Script from PHP (Nginx, php-fpm, CentOS 7)

Tags: php, bash, shell, nginx

I create php file which will execute shell script.

First is a html file, user will input their Domain and IP Address:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add new customer </title>
</head>
<link href="stylesheets/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

<h1>Add new customer for monitoring</h1>

<form method="post" action="web-add_new_customer.php">

Domain: <br />
<input type="text" name="DOMAIN" size="35" />
<br />

IP Address: <br />
<input type="text" name="IPADDRESS" size="35" />
<br /> <br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit new customer" />
<br />
</form>
```

And then, result from html file will display in some.php file to display what have been entered, and run shell script:

```html
<?php
$DOMAIN = $_POST['DOMAIN'];
$IPADDRESS = $_POST['IPADDRESS'];


if(empty($DOMAIN ) || empty($IPADDRESS )) {
echo "<h2>You must fill in all fields</h2>\n" ;
die ("Click Back to start again.");
}
echo "<h2>You Entered the following information:</h2>";
echo "<b>DOMAIN:</b><br><br>";
echo $DOMAIN;
echo "<br><br><b>IP Address:</b><br><br>";
echo $IPADDRESS;
?>

<?php
exec ( "/root/createfile.sh $DOMAIN $IPADDRESS" );
?>
```

I set createfile.sh owned by nginx. My server running nginx & php-fpm, under CentOS 7.

The php failed to execute shell script, any sugestions? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You wrote: "The php failed to execute shell script" - how did it failed exactly? Do you have an error log? Please add error text to your question

Comment: When you run the shell command from PHP that is in Apache or another server, its probably not running as `root` and as that file is in the `root` folder  `/root/createfile.sh` this tells me that you might want to check if PHP even has permission to this file.  I believe even if PHP owns that file, the directory of `root` would be off limits.

Comment: @AlexYu shell script not create any files , I see no errors in website error log.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix should I move createfile.sh to another directory? what's your sugestions?

Comment: Well I wouldn't give PHP root access, so I guess that's yes if that's the issue and if it will work from another folder. etc..

Comment: PHP most likely runs under `www-data`, so to be able to execute the script it needs to be owned by `www-data`: `chown www-data:www-data /path/to/your/script.sh`. And you should change your command to start with `sh /path/to/your/script.sh`.